# Why isnt anything showing for me except the background in the pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

Here's the code. I have both images correctly named in the same folder, so thats not the issue. Both the runner.png and the rectangle for the button don't show, but the background does.

```
class gamewindow():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.game = pygame.display.set_mode((1300, 768))
        background = pygame.image.load('temporarybackground.jpg')
        self.green = (1,255,1)
        self.buttonstart = pygame.draw.rect(self.game, self.green,(100,100, 20, 20))
        self.runner = pygame.image.load('runner.png')
        from sys import exit
        while True:
            self.game.fill((0,0,0))
            self.game.blit(background, (0, 0))

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You drew the button *once*, at the start of the program, and never drew the runner at all.  You then entered a loop that repeatedly erases the screen and draws only the background.  If you want to see anything more than that background, you have to draw it *in the loop*.

Answer (score 1):

JasonHarper's comment is correct. You're not drawing the button or runner in the loop. When you redraw the background, the other objects are erased.

Corrected code:

```
class gamewindow():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.game = pygame.display.set_mode((1300, 768))
        background = pygame.image.load('temporarybackground.jpg')
        self.green = (1,255,1)
        self.runner = pygame.image.load('runner.png')
        from sys import exit
        while True:
            self.game.fill((0,0,0)) # clear screen
            self.game.blit(background, (0, 0)) # draw background
            self.game.blit(self.runner, (50, 0)) # draw runner
            pygame.draw.rect(self.game, self.green,(100,100, 20, 20)) # draw button
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
            pygame.display.flip()
```

You also have your game code in a class constructor, which seems odd. It may be better to put your game in a standard function.